# Efficient base 2 to base 5 conversion

Tags: algorithm, memory-efficient, base-conversion

Is there any way to efficiently convert a binary string or file to base 5 without having to store all of the bits in one var as a number?
e.g. for base64, you can just make groups of  log2(64)=6 bits.

**EDIT**: Thank you for your answers, but I'll mention this once more: the algorithm should work for **files**. Doing the usual `n % base` conversion wouldn't be any good if the file is so big it can't be stored in a single int variable.

Comment: there are ez hacks for base 2(1 bit),4(2 bits),8 (3bits) base 16(4 bits)... you see the pattern..

Comment: That's why I'm asking about base 5... I can't see any memory-efficient / processing-efficient way of converting base 2 to base 5.

Comment: why do you need a base5 number anyway?

Comment: To get the least significant digit, you need to compute `n%b` where `b` is the base. There are easy ways to do that when `b` is a power of 2, but there are no shortcuts for base 5.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks, that's what I thought too.

Comment: [@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48652399/efficient-base-2-to-base-5-conversion#comment84305195_48652399): `There are easy ways to [compute n%baseⁱ]` sure. `no shortcuts for [%(baseⁱ+1)]` false: for %9, you will remember "repeated digit sum" - works just the same for, say base 4 to compute the remainder of n%3(base-1). For base+1, there is *alternate digit sum*: (sum of even numbered digits) - (sum of odd numbered digits) - may be known for %11, works just the same for %5, 5 = 2²+1.

Comment: `convert a binary string or file to base 5`, `should work for `**files** - neither `string` nor `file` have a defined order of significance. To add, a `string` is bound to feature *characters* (again, not necessarily a numeric value, nor bits with any pre-defined *endianness*); `file` to contain *octets*/*bytes*: undefined *endianness*, again. Do you think conversion to decimal any different? Would you accept a proof this can't be done (significantly) faster than [sketched by גלעד ברקן](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48663355/3789665)?

Answer (score 0):

Assumimg you'd have to store a representation of the final number in memory, we could have `O(n * d)` time, `O(d)` space, where `n` is the number of bits in the original and `d` the number of digits in the converted number, by a series of additions in base 5, keeping both the current power of 2 in base 5 (of which we add at most one of) and the result. The small advantage is generating the next `power-of-2-in-base-5` from the previous one by long multiplication mod 5:

```
44(10)
101100(2)

power-of-2-in-base-5, result
1, 0
2, 0
4, 4
13, 22
31, 22
112, 134
```

To the extent that it may provide any speedup, we can avoid actual multiplication and addition operations by table lookup, as there are only 25 combinations per operator of two operands mod 5.